# Как эффективнее всего обработать строку?

Tags: php

Приветствую. Я работаю со строками вида `/command param1 param2`, и чтобы разбить строку использовал просто `explode` по пробелу. 
Но сейчас возникла необходимость работать с такими строками: `/command "some long text" param2`. То есть мне нужно так же разбивать по пробелу, но не учитывать пробелы внутри кавычек. Как это будет правильно реализовать? 
Конечная цель - получить массив, в котором по отдельности будет команда и параметры.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
preg_match_all("/\"(.*?)(?:\"|$)|([\S]+)/u", $input, $output);
```

`$output[0]` будет содержать искомый массив

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hEV

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не могли бы вы немного пояснить, что означает `(.*?)`? Почему не просто `.*`?

Comment: Посмотрите, мой ответ был не совсем верный, я немного подправил. По поводу `?` - в данном случае `?` отменяет жадность квантификатора, иначе `.*` попросту съест всю строку.

Comment: а что съест `.*?` ? И для чего `.*?` помещать в скобки?

Comment: Первая часть до вертикальной черты жрет все от кавычки до кавычки или конца строки. Поэтому на каждый параметр в кавычках 2 совпадения - от кавычки до кавычки или от кавычки до конца. Если вы ставите `?` он выключает жадность и жрет наименьшее. Целиком сделать не жадный вариант нельзя, т.к. вторая часть выражения должна быть жадной. Ну а в скобки помещать необязательно в принципе, и так работает можно вообще все убрать `preg_match_all("/\".*?\"|$|[\S]+/", $input_lines, $output_array);`. но в `$output[1]` у вас выражения в кавычках, `$output[2]` без.

Answer (score 1):

Быстрый костыль

```
$str = 'command "some long text" param2 "this is a test yo" param3';
$exp = explode(' ', $str);

$newArr = [];
$isQuotes = false;
$str = '';

foreach ($exp as $item) {
    if (substr($item, 0, 1) == '"') 
        $isQuotes = true;

    if (substr($item, -1) == '"')   {
        $isQuotes = false;  

        if (!empty($str))
            $str .= ' '.$item;
    }

    if ($isQuotes) {
        $str .= ' '.$item;              
    } else {
        array_push($newArr, !empty($str) ? $str : $item);   
        $str = '';
    }       
}
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => command
    [1] =>  "some long text"
    [2] => param2
    [3] =>  "this is a test yo"
    [4] => param3
)
```